# Get Data From Object Array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I got problem to get data from object array.. My data array like this..

[image]

I just want get list `menuCode`.

Component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.commonService.menuList$.subscribe(data => {
      this.menuCode =  data;
      console.log(this.menuCode)
     })
  }
```

if I add code like this `this.menuCode = data['menuCode']` I got this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'menuCode' of null`. What should I do to get just `menuCode` list.

> Edit

Service

```
_getMenu() {
    this.loading.present();
    this.auth.getMenu()
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.menuList$.next(res['menuList']);
        this.loading.dismiss();
      },
      error => {
        this.menuList$.next([]);
        this.loading.dismiss();
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: can you add commonService.menuList$ logic please? And the httpClient.get/post/delete/.. of this request please? possibility that this is an HttpEvent ping event and not the actual response yet. I want to see your code first before continuing with this assumption.

Comment: Also try logging `data` to the console to see if you are indeed getting something back.

Comment: I've add commonService.menuList$  as you wish..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your res object is an array of objects. So doing `res['menuCode']` is going to return null because it doesn't exist on the array. So if you want to get a list of menuCodes, you can use the `map()` function

```
_getMenu() {
    this.loading.present();
    this.auth.getMenu()
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.menuList$.next(res.map(r => r.menuCode)); // here
        this.loading.dismiss();
      },
      error => {
        this.menuList$.next([]);
        this.loading.dismiss();
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. But I got error..`Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'`

Comment: the picture of your console in your question, is that your `console.log(this.menuCode)`? If not, where is that coming from?

Comment: Yes true...I using `console.log(this.menuCode)`

Comment: After I modified like this it work `this.menuCodeList$.next(res['menuList'].map(r => r.menuCode));`